# Mongo 2.6 isMaster() result after setting readPref to secondary

Tags: javascript, mongodb

We recently upgraded mongo from 2.4 to 2.6 and have noticed that our connection code is staying with the primary host instead of connecting to the secondaries. This is despite the following commands.

```
var connectHost = "rsComplex/complex0,complex1,complex2/data";
var mainDB = connect(connectHost);
mainDB.getMongo().setReadPref("secondary");
mainDB.isMaster() produces


Is Master
{
    "setName" : "rsComplex",
    "setVersion" : 77003,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "hosts" : [
            "complex1:27017",
            "complex0:27017",
            "complex2:27017"
    ],
    "primary" : "complex1:27017",
    "me" : "complex1:27017",
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2014-11-19T16:23:21.612Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 2,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

We also use db.setSlaveOk() which previously worked.

Is this to be expected?  In 2.4, I would see - master : false, and me != primary.

Thanks,

Comment: If you send reads do they work off of the secondary? The primary is still needed for all writes so it doesn't surprise me that you could see what you're seeing here. If the secondary read preference is respected then I don't think there's a problem, right?

Comment: @wdberkeley Is there is a clean way to find out if the reads are heading to the secondaries? I assume cursor.explain() should work.